# How to exit raw mode without a trace in C?

Tags: c, exit, reset, text-editor

I have followed the tutorial on how to make a text editor [here.](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken) An annoying thing is that when the program exits raw mode, it doesn't show my previous commands. For example, if my shell prompt looks like this:

```
$ ls
$ gcc main.c -o main -Wall -std=c99 -Wextra -pedantic
$
```

and I run the text editor and quit it, it will look like this:

```
$
```

Can I get it to look like this:

```
$ ls
$ gcc main.c -o main -Wall -std=c99 -Wextra -pedantic
$ kilo main.c
$
```

Here's the code for entering raw mode, if that's helpful.

```
 void enableRawMode(){
     if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &E.orig_termios) == -1) die("tcgetattr");
     atexit(disableRawMode);
     struct termios raw = E.orig_termios;
     raw.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON);
     raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
     raw.c_cflag |= ~(CS8);
     raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
     raw.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
     raw.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
     if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw) == -1) die("tcsetattr");
 }
```

Comment: You need to send the appropriate control sequence to the terminal on start up and on exit.  That's wholly separate from the rawness etc.  I forget what the terminfo capabilities are called, but you'll need that information.

Comment: @ARI FISHER If you press Shift + PgUp do you see your previous commands?

Comment: Yes.. kind of? I'm using a laptop so I don't really have Shift + PgUp but I can scroll, it's just repostitioned. However, if I scroll up I see the editor.

Comment: No. It's kind of weird.